# Intersecting two strings

Tags: string-manipulation

Is there a simple way to intersect two strings? I did not find anything about that.

```
intersect["abcdEfgh","blahcdEzz"] (* "cdE" *)
```

By intersection, I mean the longest substring(s) that is(are) common to both strings.

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LongestCommonSubsequence.html

Comment: @V.E. Perfect. Feel free to write an answer for completeness...

Comment: Just one click on V.E.'s hint gives the answer...

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Turning the comment into an answer allows me to accept it, and hence remove this question for the unanswered list.

Comment: @ anderstood: I got it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As porposed by @V.E. you should use `LongestCommonSubsequence[s1,s2]`. Example from the documentation:

```
LongestCommonSubsequence[ "AAABBBBCCCCC", "CCCBBBAAABABA"]
(* AAAB *)
```